# 504 Gateway Error in NextJS Vercel for simple POST Request to MongoD

Tags: mongodb, post, next.js, vercel

```
  useEffect(
    () => {
      if (user) {
        const uid = user.uid;
        const email = user.email;
        const displayName = user.displayName;
        console.log("User has signed in, attempting to post user info:");
        console.log(uid, email, displayName);
        fetch("/api/storeUser", {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            uid: uid,
            email: email,
            displayName: displayName,
          }),
        })
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((data) => {
            console.log("Successfully posted user login info to MongoDB", data);
            // Redirect or perform additional actions upon successful POST
            router.push("/");
          })
          .catch((error) => console.error("Error storing user:", error));
      }
    },
    user,
    router
  );
```

```
export async function POST(req, res) {
  // console.log("User post request", req.body);
  const { uid, email, displayName } = await req.json();
  // console.log("User post request", uid, email, displayName);
  await connectMongoDB();
  // let user = await User.findOne({ uid });
  // if (!user) {
  //   await User.create({ uid, email, displayName });
  // }
  await User.create({ uid, email, displayName });
  return NextResponse.json(
    { message: "User created successfully!" },
    { status: 200 }
  );
}
```

This is just a simple POST request I want to make after a user has signed into my application. The console logs show everything correctly but I am getting 504 Gateway Error. POSTMAN and logging in on localhost works perfectly. I have allowed access from anywhere on MongoDB. I have built several other projects prior to this. I dont think I should be upgrading my Vercel from Hobby for this project as well.

I initially tried posting from /login but nothing worked. I have tried setting states and constants before posting, but still nothing. I wondered if it was because of some complications behind the asynchronous function of signInWithGoogle I used. So, i switched to POSTing after the user has reached the LANDING page.

What i want is just to store the 3 user details (uid, email, displayName) in my MongoDB. But I keep getting 504 error on Vercel's deployment. It works perfectly on localhost:3000 and the response time is really really low.